# Maximum recursion depth exceeded error in Python while implementing Binary Search Tree

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, binary-search-tree

I was using Python to learn BST and tried implementing insert and find methods. But I was getting Maximum recursion depth exceeded error in insertNode method. I am new to BST data structure and hence struggling to implement the methods in Python. I tried researching and making my code similar to ones on the internet, but I am still getting the error.

```
class Node:
def __init__(self,data):
    self.data = data
    self.left = None
    self.right = None

class BST:
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = None  
    def insert(self,data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if self.root is None:
            self.root = temp
        else:
            self.insertNode(self.root,data)  
    def insertNode(self,root,data):
        temp = Node(data)
        if data < self.root.data:
            if self.root.left is None:
                self.root.left = temp
            else:
                self.insertNode(self.root.left,data)
        elif data > self.root.data:
            if self.root.right is None:
                self.root.right = temp
            else:
                self.insertNode(self.root.right,data)
    def findinTree(self,root,data):
        if self.root is None:
            return False
        if data == self.root.data:
            return True
        if data < self.root.data:
            self.findinTree(self.root.left,data)
        else:
            self.findinTree(self.root.right,data)
        return False


bst = BST()
bst.insert(30)
bst.insert(10)
bst.insert(50)
bst.insert(90)
bst.insert(100)
bst.insert(15)
```

Please help debug the error so that the functions work as intended.

Comment: What is the exact error and on what line does it occur? Can you paste the error trace here?

Comment: you could increase the recursion limit with `sys.setrecursionlimit`. just be careful, python stackframes can get pretty big.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 47, in <module>
  File "python", line 16, in insert
  File "python", line 29, in insertNode
  File "python", line 29, in insertNode
  File "python", line 29, in insertNode
  File "python", line 29, in insertNode  File "python", line 19, in insertNode
RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded @ShreyasG

Comment: Please update your question with the stack trace - it will be easier to read. Also I can see problems in your code, for instance in: `def insertNode(self,root,data):` you have a `root` parameter which you don't use inside the method.

Comment: Also, you are creating way too many temp Nodes. You could create a Node only when really needed.

Answer (score 2):

These methods might be the **root** ;-) cause of the problem:

```
def insertNode(self, root, data):
    if data < root.data:  # <- use the root parameter ...
        if root.left is None:
            root.left = Node(data)
        else:
            self.insertNode(root.left, data)
    else:
        if root.right is None:
            root.right = Node(data)
        else:
            self.insertNode(root.right, data)

def findinTree(self, root, data):
    if root is None:
        return False
    if data == root.data:
        return True
    if data < root.data:
        return self.findinTree(root.left, data)
    else:
        return self.findinTree(root.right, data)
```

**NB** *code not tested*

*Update:* took suggestion of VPfB and did not create unnecessary nodes.

Comment: Thank you but I also have another question. If I am making "findinTree" method this way, how would I pass in the parameter "root" while calling this method via object ?

Comment: The same way you've done the `insert` method. You write yourself a `find` wrapper method. Any upvotes or accepted answer would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

In `insertNode` you refer to `self.root` which is the tree's root. Instead, you should refer `root`, the function parameter.

In fact, after the 1st sub-level is created (`bst.insert(50)`), the right branch of the tree's root is not `None` anymore and so it keeps calling `self.insertNode(self.root.right,data)`

```
def insertNode(self,root,data):                                                                                                                                                                          
    temp = Node(data)                                                                                                                                                                                    
    if data < root.data:                                                                                                                                                                                 
        if root.left is None:                                                                                                                                                                            
            print("Inserting {} on the left branch of {}".format(data, root.data))                                                                                                                       
            root.left = temp                                                                                                                                                                             
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                            
            print("Inserting {} on the left branch of {}".format(data, root.data))                                                                                                                       
            self.insertNode(root.left,data)                                                                                                                                                              
    elif data > root.data:                                                                                                                                                                               
        if root.right is None:                                                                                                                                                                           
            print("Inserting {} on the right branch of {}".format(data, root.data))                                                                                                                      
            root.right = temp                                                                                                                                                                            
        else:                                                                                                                                                                                            
            print("Inserting {} on the right branch of {}".format(data, root.data))                                                                                                                      
            self.insertNode(root.right,data)
```

Comment: General programming advice - do NOT use the same name for a function parameter as for an object property. It's too easy to make the mistake which Daniele Bacarella has caught.